# JPA: Filter entries of a ManyToMany Relationship in the non-owning side

Tags: jpa, filter, where-clause, many-to-many

I have two JPA Entites: A and B (both simplified for better understanding)

```
@Entity 
public class A {
  
  @Id
  private String aUuid 

  fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(...)
  private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>(); 
  
  ...
}
```

```
@Entity 
public class B {
  
  @Id
  private String bUuid 

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "aList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>(); 
  
  ...
}
```

I now want that the aList in class B gets initialised with only linked entities of A: Where uuid == x.
I cannot swap the owning side of the relationship.
Is there some annotation where i can specify a filter or a query to exclude entries that dont satisfy the condition?